Google Workspace - Method: domains.trafficStats.list
I have multiple email domains where the domain traffic has been being tracked with Google Postmaster Tools.  The problem is the domain traffic, including the spam rate, IP reputation, domain reputation, etc. have been being tracked manually and one by one.
So essentially, to get the items I listed above, one must go into Google Postmaster Tools, click on one of the domains, and get the needed information one by one.
There are well over 20 domains.  Going into each domain one by one is time consuming.
I found this Google Workspace: https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/reference/rest/v1/domains.trafficStats/list
On the right side, there is an API explorer that you can enter a domain, as well as end dates and start dates, and it will spit out a JSON object with the domain traffic information.
The problem with that is again will only allow 1 domain at a time.  Although this may speed up the retrieval of the data needed, but I'm trying to find a way where I can get all of the data I need in one spot.
How can I get a JSON object to spit out all of the domains and all of their traffic stats? I just can't find anything like that.
